# org/springframework/core/AliasRegistry not found

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2

I have developed demo application using spring struct and hibernate and getting following error while running it.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/AliasRegistry
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:239)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
```

through google i came to know that problem might be because of some version conflict of spring library
So following is the jar list, i added in my application.

```
commons-digester-2.0.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-chain-1.2.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
spring-core-2.5.jar
javassist.jar
spring-jdbc-2.5.jar
spring-beans-2.5.6.jar
spring-context-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
hibernate3.jar
oro-2.0.8.jar
struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
antlr-2.7.2.jar
struts-tiles-1.3.10.jar
struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar
struts-extras-1.3.10.jar
com.springsource.org.dom4j-1.6.1.jar
commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
spring-context-support-2.5.jar
spring-orm-2.5.jar
spring-tx-2.5.6.jar
spring-web-2.5.jar
spring-webmvc-struts-2.5.jar
```

Comment: i am confused you have strus1,Struts2 different version of Spring jars.As suggested please make sure there is no conflict between the versions

Comment: I don't know which version of spring is compatible with struts2.x. Shall i know compatible version of spring ?

Comment: Yes you are right its my fault it needs all spring jar of 2.5.6 version thanks a lot for suggestion.

Comment: S2 is compatible even with spring 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use same version for all Spring dependencies. Now you are using 2.5 and 2.5.6.

Answer (score 0):

The jar file that own `AliasRegistry` is from spring-core-2.5.jar and from your libraries output, it seem you have that. I have once with mixed version 3 and version 2.5 of spring causing issue. But the exceptions are gone once the correct version are in place.

I have struts1.3 and hibernate, I will comment based on our difference and to see if this give you any help. But with my libraries placed in lib, hibernate works fine though. So here goes,

- Get the same version for this.

  ```
  commons-digester-2.0.jar
  commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
  ```
- which version of `javassist.jar` do you have? I have `javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar`
- `spring-beans-2.5.6.jar`, try get exact version of `spring-beans-2.5.jar`
- which exact version of `hibernate3.jar` do you have? I'm using `hibernate-core-3.6.4.Final.jar`
- These are libraries for struts1, are you using these together with struts2?

  ```
  struts-tiles-1.3.10.jar
  struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar
  struts-extras-1.3.10.jar
  commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
  ```
- these seem like packages from struts2 which is the one you are using, yes?

  ```
  struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar
  xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar
  ```
- try to get the exact version of spring-tx, that is `spring-tx-2.5.jar` which is the same with the rest of spring jars.